# How to make a percentage circle using using html and css only with percentage written inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a circle using html and css only. But I want a certain percent number like 70% or 80% written inside it. And the cirlce should be only as much complete as the number states.

I have already tried it, making circle is not difficult but I can't find a way to write a certain percentage inside the circle and make sure that circle is as much complete as the number states.

I know a bit of html and css only and I'm not sure if this can be achieved using these 2 only.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and recommendation, but I don't want to use JS as mentioned, want to achieve this using html and css only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/michalburda/pen/KNWqRZ/) might help you by Andre Firchow. Although it uses SCSS
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c100 p99 blue">
      <span>90%</span>
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c100 p75 pink">
      <span>75%</span>
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c100 p70 green">
      <span>70%</span>
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c100 p85 orange">
      <span>85%</span>
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
// Compass utilities
@import "compass";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900');

body {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

// VARS
$circle-width: 0.09em;
$circle-width-hover: 0.07em;

// colors default
$primary-color: #000000; // czarny
$secondary-color: #dfe8ed; //szary bcg
$bg-color: #ffffff; //srodkowy bezowy 

// colors customized
$primary-color-blue: #30bae7;
$primary-color-green: #15c7a8;
$primary-color-orange: #eb7d4b; 
$primary-color-pink: #d74680; 
$primary-color-span: #3c4761;

// CIRCLE
// classes 2 extend
.rect-auto{
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    border: $circle-width solid $primary-color;
    width: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
    height: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    border-radius: 50%;
    @include rotate(0deg);
}

.pie-fill {
    @include rotate(180deg);
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


// main
.c100 {

    *, *:before, *:after {
        @include box-sizing(content-box);
    }

    position: relative;
    font-size: 160px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.4em;
    background-color: $secondary-color;

    // centered value inside circle
    > span {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 5em;
        line-height: 5em;
        font-size: 0.2em;
        color: $primary-color-span;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.2s);
        @include transition-timing-function(ease-out);
    }

    // background inside the circle
    &:after{
        position: absolute;
        top: $circle-width;
        left: $circle-width;
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: $bg-color;
        width: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
        height: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
        @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.2s);
        @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);

    }

    // the slice (mask)
    .slice {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
    }

    // circle to show the status
    .bar {
        @extend .pie;
    }


    // loop to create all needed elements automatically
    @for $j from 51 through 100 {

        &.p#{$j} .slice {
            @extend .rect-auto;
        }

        &.p#{$j} .bar:after{
            @extend .pie-fill;
        }

        &.p#{$j} .fill{
            @extend .pie;
            @extend .pie-fill;
        }

    }

    // loop to rotate all 100 circles
    @for $j from 1 through 100 {
        &.p#{$j} .bar {
            @include rotate((360/100*$j) + deg);
        }
    }



    // hover styles
    &:hover{

        cursor: default;

        > span {
            width: 3.33em;
            line-height: 3.33em;
            font-size: 0.3em;
            color: $primary-color-span;
        }

        &:after{
            top: $circle-width-hover;
            left: $circle-width-hover;
            width: 1 - (2 * $circle-width-hover);
            height: 1 - (2 * $circle-width-hover);
        }

    }

    // blue
    &.blue{

        .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-blue !important;}

        &:hover{
            > span { color: $primary-color-span;}
        }

    }


    // pink skin
    &.pink{

        .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-pink !important;}

        &:hover{
            > span { color: $primary-color-span;}
        }

    }


    // green skin
    &.green{

        .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-green !important;}

        &:hover{
            > span { color: $primary-color-span;}
        }

    }


    // orange skin
    &.orange{

        .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-orange !important;}

        &:hover{
            > span { color: $primary-color-span;}
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. How can you pass some data like the percentage without using some JS to manipulate the css

Comment: You could use CSS variables to pass the desired percentage.